Proof using mathematical induction for inequlity
How do I prove the inequality $2^n>3(n−1)$ using mathematical induction?
I know that first I have to show that this holds for $n = 1$
LHS: $2^1 = 2$
RHS: $3(1-1) = 0$
∴ LHS > RHS
Next I have to assume this holds for $k$, i.e $2^k>3(k−1), Ǝk ∈ ℕ$, right?
Then I have to prove that this holds for k+1, i.e $2^{k+1}>3(k+1−1)$ or $2^{k+1}>3k$, right?
LHS: $2^{k+1} = 2.2^k > 2.3(k−1) > 6k-6$
How do I prove $6k-6 > 3k$.
Also, this is not true for k = 1, does that contradict $Ǝk ∈ ℕ$
I have seen example inequality proofs with addition signs where it is clear that LHS is greater than RHS, but not any with subtractions.

$2\cdot3(k-1)\color{blue}=6k-6$, and $6k-6\ge3k $ for $k\ge2$

@J.W.Tanner Does it not matter that it does not hold for $k = 1$

Check $k=1$ separately and induct with the base case $k=2$.

@ultralegend5385 So I have to show that it holds for 1 and 2 first?

Yes.............
